# Changing VBA code in hundreds of Excel files without opening every one of them

Tags: python, loops, nested

I have a data base of hundreds of submitted forms, every submitted form contains various modules with VBA code in them to process the data.

Each form file name starts with same unique prefix.

All of the forms are saved in our main global directory of documents.

Data from every form is logged into a log file.

VBA code within each forms allow me to change information in the form and send the updated information into the log.

Now because of the office 2019 being introduced, vb scripts in every form made in 2016 version is not working and I have to force change the code in every single form to make it compatible with 2019.

This mass change is not only required due to office version change but also required because I need to update log file with additional information contained within the forms cells which old VBA code does not process.

There are 4 VBA modules in every form file and scripts in every modules needs to be replaced with the new code.

Really don't know where to start, any ideas are much appreciated.

I have no idea what to try.

Expected result is that I have updated/new code for 4 macro modules currently exist in 100's of files which needs to be replaced over the old codes.. of excel files starting with a common unique prefix.

Comment: Any comment on the answer that I supplied?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to modify VBA projects. For this, the *"Trust access to the VBA project object model"* checkbox must be ticked in the Trust Center/Macro Settings.

After that, open the VBA editor. Set a reference to *"Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3"* (possibly the version is different for you, I don't know).

Now a couple of additional classes become available under the `VBIDE` library and those can be used to manipulate VBA projects programmatically. (I'm using this feature to export VBA modules for source control.)

There is no easy way to modify the text of the module, but you can try exporting, deleting and re-importing them to see if that already is enough:

```vb
Sub Test()
  Dim vbcs As VBIDE.VBComponents
  Dim vbc As VBIDE.VBComponent
  Dim filename As String

  Set vbcs = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

  For Each vbc In vbcs
    Debug.Print vbc.name
    If vbc.name = "The ones you want" Then
      filename = GetFilenameFromModule(vbc)
      vbc.Export filename
      ' you could modify the file contents now if needed
      vbcs.Remove vbc
      vbcs.Import filename
    End If
  Next vbc
End Sub

Private Function GetFilenameFromModule(vbc As VBIDE.VBComponent) As String
  Select Case vbc.Type
    Case vbext_ct_ClassModule, vbext_ct_Document:
      GetFilenameFromModule = vbc.name & ".cls"
    Case vbext_ct_MSForm:
      GetFilenameFromModule = vbc.name & ".frm"
    Case vbext_ct_StdModule:
      GetFilenameFromModule = vbc.name & ".bas"
  End Select
End Function
```

Be sure to check out the properties of the various objects in the debugger or object browser (F2), just to see what's available. I'm not sure how well documented all of that is, but it's versatile and stable.

To work with files in VBA easily, you can set a reference to the *"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"* library and use the FileSystemObject.